# what is BlockingDeque in Java?

Tags: list

As the question say, what is BlockingDeque in Java?

Comment: `Elements div= document.getElementsByTag("div");` is not used anywhere, you can remove that line. Aside from that, what exactly is the problem you are facing? What you want this code to do and what it does instead?

Comment: OK you stated your goal, but didn't clarify what is stopping you from achieving it. Generally we can say that you want to (1) iterate over each HTML file in some directory (2) find all divs with id starting with `part_` (3) get their text (4) write that text to some file. Which step you have trouble with?

Comment: @beartown Try `div.wholeText()` instead of `div.text()` .

Comment: For HTML example you posted your code gives me `Part 2 : Security measures
Part 3 security To review ... ... measures to adjust`. If that is not what you are getting then maybe you are not parsing document you think you are parsing. If it is right document and you are also getting same results then can you explain problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. Jsoup is actually intuitive and pretty straightforward:

To select all divs having an id attribute and a value starting with "part" just use: `doc.select("div[id^=part]");`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document document = Jsoup.parse( new File( "C:\\Users\\Eritrean\\Desktop\\delete.html" ) , "utf-8" );
    Elements myDivs = document.select("div[id^=part_]");
    myDivs.forEach(d -> {System.out.println(d.wholeText());});
}
```

Output:

```
Part 2 : Security measures 

     Part 3
security To review  

 ... 
 ...

measures to adjust
```

Look at the [Jsoup cookbook](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

See the [Selector API reference](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write your answer. I'm working on long, multiple html files ( more than 200), so I can't really write each one of them as a string. That being said, i tried your code sample and it didn't give me any result ( no error but an empty console ).

Comment: @beartown I have copied your sample html snippet and saved it as a html file and with the above code I definitely get an output. For your information I use jsoup in the current version **1.13.1**  [JSoup Java HTML Parser 1.13.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.13.1)